# How can I export Google analitycs data in java?

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api

I am trying to get Google analitycs information : "acquisition -> all traffic -> channels" by the secound column: users.

What metrics and dimensions should I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ga:users` as metric and `ga:channelGrouping` as dimension.